# How to create/use shared domain properties/methods in Grails 2?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

before Grails 2.x we used an abstract class to model shared domain properties. This worked perfect but now when using Grails 2.x is see no way of creating shared domain properties and methods. When i use an abstract class and let my domain classes extend that abstract class i get one big database table.

Is there a alternative way of creating shared domain properties / methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html) says that you need to move your base class into the `/src/groovy` at this case

Comment: This does not seem to work as i would expect. Whenever i put additional properties in an abstract class and put that class into the src/grooy.. And after that let my domain class extend that abstract class. The original class is not a domain class anymore. I do not get the database tables anymore. Also constraints in the abstract class in the src/groovy give a compile error when i doing this.

Comment: Probably i did something wrong but indeed placing he abstract class into src/groovy now works :) Thanks for the tip!